# Java: XMLEncoder writeObject child object

Tags: java, parent-child

I'm doing a little homework on Java, but I'm not good at it and I'm having issues trying to use XMLEncoder to store an App objects to a file.

In short my App has and abstract class called `animal` and another ones that extend the previous one called `dog`and `cat`. In my main App I've a static method to create new animals that adds the new animal object to a static ArrayList of type `animal`: `public static ArrayList<animal> animalArray = new ArrayList<animal>();`

Creating an animal at 
**kingdom.java:**

```
private static void newAnimal(ArrayList<animal> animalArray) {
            System.out.print("  Enter a name for the dog > ");
            animalArray.add(new dog(keyboard.nextLine()));
            System.out.println("  New dog with name " + animalArray.get(animalArray.size()-1).getName() + ".\n");

            try {
                FileOutputStream afos = new FileOutputStream("animals.xml");
                XMLEncoder encoder = new XMLEncoder(afos);
                encoder.writeObject(animalArray.get(animalArray.size()-1));
                encoder.close();
            } catch(IOException ioe){
                System.out.print("[ERROR!]");
            }
}
```

My abstract animal class:
**animal.java:**

```
public abstract class animal {

    private static int alloc = 0;
    protected int id;
    private String name;

    animal() {
        alloc++;
        id = alloc;
    }

    public void play() {
        System.out.print("   The animal (" + this.id + ") " + this.name + " is now playing... ");
    }

    public void setName(String lname) {
        this.name = lname;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public static int countAnimals() {
        return alloc;
    }

}
```

Now, my dog class:
**dog.java:**

```
public class dog extends animal {

    dog(String theName) {
        this.setName(theName);
    }

    @Override
    public void play() {
        super.play();
        System.out.println(" Dog Stuff!");
    }

}
```

**When I try to run the code I get:**

```
java.lang.InstantiationException: dog
Continuing ...
java.lang.Exception: XMLEncoder: discarding statement XMLEncoder.writeObject(dog);
Continuing ...
```

What am I missing? Thank you ;)

Comment: Wont `dog` require a no-arg constructor for normal usage? (This is somewhat unlike Java Serialisation.) It's also well worth sticking to the naming conventions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use as following:

**encoder.writeObject(animalArray.get(animalArray.size()-1).getName());**

The Dog object itself can't be saved into XMLEncoder.

Thx.